# How to bypass media selection command to printer when using Ghostscript rip ps files?

Tags: ghostscript

I am trying to use GhostScript to rip PostScript files first on computer and then forward them to a ricoh MP1350 printer through USB connection, but failed. So I hereby ask for help. The detail is as following.

Followed the instructions provided on [www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSPSPrinter/GSPSprinter.html](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/%7Ehenrik/GSPSPrinter/GSPSprinter.html), I succeeded in building a virtual PS printer on a PC with Win7.

I setup the virtual PS printer with MP1350 PS driver, creating the redirect port RPT1 with argument told by the instruction and in help with RedMon, all printing data were forwarded to the real MP1350 device connected with the PC through USB.

It DOES work when dealing with common printing jobs. However, when I send PostScript files containing MP1350's media selection commands, it seems fail to tell the printer to fetch paper in tray 2 or 3 or 4 as told in that PS file. All pieces of paper are fetched in tray 1.

The print command is:

> copy /b sample.ps \\127.0.0.1\gspspr

in which "gspspr" is the printer name of the virtual PS printer, with MP1350 PS driver Ver3.1(latest) installed. "sample.ps" is the postscript file I mentioned above.

The arguments file "mswinpr2.txt" is written as follow:

```
-Ic:\gs\gs9.05\lib
    -sDEVICE=mswinpr2
    -dNoCancel
    -dNOPAUSE
    -dSAFER
    -dMaxBitmap=400000000
    -dBufferSpace=400000000
    -dNumRenderingThreads=2
    -dMaxPatternBitmap=80000000
    -sPAPERSIZE=a4
```

With the same PostScript file "sample.ps", if I send it using this command:

> copy /b sample.ps \\127.0.0.1\gsprinter

in which "gsprinter" is the name of real MP1350 connected through USB, with MP1350 PS driver Ver3.1(latest) installed. The printer MP1350 can tell those media selection commands and fetch paper from tray 2 or 3 or 4 as told.

All the driver settings of these two devices are the **same**, and I set output protocol to "**TBCP**" in "**Device Settings**" tab.

So please help me to tell, why the printer fails to select the certain media trays when I use gs to rip that ps file? And how to solve it?

With great appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

The PostScript file contains the media and tray selection command,s if you send the PostScript to the printer directly, then those commands are acted upon by the printer.

When you use Ghostscript, you are actually rendering the PostScript to a bitmap, which the mswinpr2 device forwards to the windows printing system. The final printer can be anything, it need not be a PostScript printer. However you can't embed tray selection commands in the bitmap, so there is no way to preserve that request form the original job.

There is no way to 'solve' this, its in the nature of the process.

Given that your printer clearly accepts PostScript directly why are you even using Ghostscript at all ?

Comment: Because the rip speed is still a bit slow when deal with some kind of big size PS files, and I try to speed them up by this way. It's odd that it does work when I use a Canon iRC5180 with H1 server to make this similar experiment. </br> So does there exist any way to speed up the rip speed of MP1350? Or if there is possibility to compose a ghostscript to divide those tray selection commands out and deliver them to printer separately?

Comment: Ghostscript is not producing the data which is fed to your printer when you run in this mode. All it does is render the incoming PostScript to a bitmap. The file which is sent to your printer is generated by the Windows Printing System. So there is *nothing* you can do with Ghostscript in this mode which will affect the tray selection on the printer, as that is entirely performed by the print system. I do not know anything about the 'H1' server, I don't even know what it is. As for improving the printer performance, add more memory is all I can suggest.

Comment: Thank you all the same for making me clear about these staffs. Another question, does Ghostscript has any mode which could affect the tray selection on printer while ripping PS files? It seems that the largest print memory capacity of MP1350 is 512M and it is now.:(

Comment: Basically, no. You could try running the ps2write device which transforms PostScript into PostScript. That probably sounds pointless, but its possible the transformed PostScript (which is pretty simple-minded) would run faster on your printer than the original. That still wouldn't add any tray selection however, as there is no support for passing such data through. However the resulting PostScript file is a well-formed DSC compliant file, you could easily write a script to add tray selection commands to the output PS file.

Comment: Great appreciation! I think I've got your idea. But which difficult to me is that I am a user but a developer of GS/PS, so I don't know how to write this script and where to put it to make things work. What a shame.

Answer (score 0):

If your printer understands PCL5 or PCL6, you can rip your files through ghostscript and have ghostscript mapping the postscript MediaPosition to trays in HP-like printers.
Two of the ghostscript drivers - ljet4 (or one of the pcl5? ones) and pxlcolor, 
can map postscript mediaposition to HP media trays. See also discussion on the InputAttributes dictionary and the -dNOMEDIAATRS switch, however. http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693053

Comment: This comment seems open another door to me. I will do a research on what you referred to me. Thanks so much!